# Mongoose: как сделать populate вложенного объекта

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Всем привет. Есть такой код:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const http = require('http');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    purchases: [{
        product: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'product',
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1
        }
    }]
});

const User = module.exports.user = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);


const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    description: String,
    price: Number
});

const Product = module.exports.product = mongoose.model('product', ProductSchema);


mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/megatest', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
})
    .then(async () => {
        mongoose.connection.collections.users.drop();
        mongoose.connection.collections.products.drop();

        const newUser = new User({
            name: 'Bill',
            email: 'lolwhat@omg.xu',
            password: 'qwerty',
        });
        const newProduct = new Product({
            description: 'Ferrari',
            price: 5000
        });

        newUser.purchases.push(newProduct);

        try {
            await Promise.all([newUser.save(), newProduct.save()]);
            http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
                const user = await User.findOne({name: 'Bill'}).populate({
                    path: 'purchases.product',
                });
                res.end(JSON.stringify(user));
            }).listen(3000);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('We have a problem: ' + e);
        }
    })
.catch((e) => {
    console.log('Problem with mongoDB: ' + e);
});
```

Это упрощеный вариант того над чем бьюсь, не суть. Обратите внимание что поле 'purchases' это массив с доп полем quantity и ссылками на 'product'. Проблема в том что никак не удается сделать populate объекта user чтобы массив 'purchases' был заполнен не id и полем quantity а самими 'покупками'. Пробовал разные вариант:

```
populate({
path: 'purchases',
populate: {
path: 'product',
// model: 'product'
}
})
```

И так и сяк, никак не работает. Что не так, где ошибся? Хелп!

Answer (score -1):

Сам спросил, сам ответил. Все оказалось проще некуда - нужно сделать populate('purchases._id'). Указываем путь к ID, а не к названию поля